# Facebook add comment data format

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, foreach, facebook-comments

I want to add comment on facebook post.. via facebook API

The function that adds the comment is

```
public function fill($json)
{
    if(isset($json['data']))
    {
        $json = $json['data'];
    }
    foreach($json as $k => $v ) $this->{$k} = $v;
}
```

I am passing the data in json format as

```
{"data":{"id":"153870348034313_347443752010304","message":"test comment"}}
```

but the response is: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't decode the `JSON`:

```
public function fill($json)
{
    $json = json_decode($json);

    if(isset($json->data))
    {
        $json = $json->data;
    }
    foreach($json as $k => $v ) $this->{$k} = $v;
}
```